# Can you help me on the MPC theory Teminal ingredients?

Tags: convex-optimization, optimal-control, geometric-construction, model-predictive-control

Can [you help me on the MPC theory Teminal ingredients ? more in particulat on the Ellipsoid constrained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBtVK.png)

You can see the picture.

Comment: Please transcribe to MathJax

Answer (score 0):

The ellipsoid you need to find can be numerically computed by solving the following optimization problem.

Let me denote $X_K\triangleq\{x|H_uKx\leq h_u\}=\{x|a_{u,i}^\top x\leq b_{u,i}, i = 1,...,n_u\}$ the polyhedral set that satisfies the condition $x\in X_K,Kx\in U$. Then, your problem can be regarded as a well-known problem of finding a maximum volume inscribed ellipsoid (See more detail here at Section 8.4.2 in [this book](https://www.ie.bilkent.edu.tr/%7Emustafap/courses/bv_cvxbook.pdf) of Stephen Boyd together with the theoretical proof employing the hint you have).
More specifically, you need to find the ellipsoid $E=\{x|x^\top P x\leq \alpha\}$ so that it is inscribed in $X_K$. To align our problem with the representation in the book, the ellipsoid $E$ can be rewritten as the following form:
$$  
E=\{x=\sqrt\alpha Bv, \forall v^\top v \leq 1,v\in\mathbb R^n\}
$$
where $B$ can be computed as $B=((U\sqrt S V^\top)^\top )^{-1}$ with[U,S,V] come from the singular value decomposition of $P$, $(P=USV^\top)$. The transformation between these two representations can be found in more detail [in this paper](https://tcg.mae.cornell.edu/pubs/Pope_FDA_08.pdf). Then, with $\beta=\sqrt\alpha$, $\beta$ can be found by solving the following convex optimization problem:
$$
\beta^*=\underset{\beta}{\arg \max \log \det(\beta B)}
$$
$$
\text{subject to: } \|\beta B a_{u,i}\|_2\leq b_{u,i}, \,i = 1,...,n_u.
$$
This is known to be a convex optimization problem and, particularly for your question, it has only one scalar variable $\beta$. With this, you can have the value of $\alpha=\beta^2$ for your problem. Implementation of this problem was already discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456854/finding-the-maximum-volume-inscribed-ellipsoid-using-cvx) with CVX solver.